# Access dag_run.conf in a custom pythonoperator on Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I extended the existing PythonOperator on Airflow as follow:

```
class myPythonOperator(PythonOperator):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs) -> None:
        self.name = kwargs.get("name", "name is not provided")      

    def execute(self, context,**kwargs):
        print(self.name)
        super(myPythonOperator, self).execute(context)
```

And my task was defined as:

```
def task1(**kwargs):
    name = kwargs.get("name", "name is not provided")
    print(name)
```

And with the following DAG:

```
    myTask = myPythonOperator(
    task_id='myTask',
    python_callable = task1,
    op_kwargs={"name": "{{ dag_run.conf['name'] }}"},
    provide_context=True
)
```

When triggering the DAG, I provided a configuration JSON from Airflow web UI, which is `{"name":"foo"}`

But the problem is that the name specified in JSON can only be access from task1, in `ececute()` it will always print `name is not provided`

Does anyone know the trick to access this `dag_run.conf` from the `__init__()` function of the operator?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to access dag.run_config from a inherited class is by using template_field in Airflow, which can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#templating)